# Получение данных из Excel (Java)

Tags: java, excel

Читал я и про Apache POI и про jexcelapi,и про jdbc способ, про всё это читал, но ни где,повторяюсь нигде, не нашел годного гайда или туториала,или примеров как правильно считывать данные из excel-таблицы.

В моем случае формат файла - xlsx.

В данном файле есть 5 листов.

Ищу адекватный пример по чтению данных построчно из excel-таблицы формата xlsx.

В своем примере укажите, что отвечает за чтение, что за формат, что за путь к файлу.

Просто весь на нервах уже час убил на поиск адекватной библиотеки и конструктивному и понятному туториалу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моя статья, года 2 назад писал, и тамвполне адекватный пример, во всяком случае, он компилируется, работает и максимально прост, проект можно скачать целиком если зарегистрироваться:

http://codeproject.com/Tips/990914/Csharp-VB-NET-Cplusplus-CLI-Java-Work-With-MS-Ex

> В своем примере укажите, что отвечает за чтение, что за формат, что за путь к файлу.

А это уже сами разбирайтесь! Со временем разовьется декомпозиционное мышление и станет хорошо получаться, а чужих ответов все равно на все вопросы не хватит, если только платить кому-то за каждый ответ, и то порой придется немало платить и немало ждать.

> Просто весь на нервах уже час убил

И стрессоустойчивость развивайте, я на нервах только дня через три бываю. Но моментально ее не развить, поэтому необходим отдых, даже если работа успешно выполнена, но сильно устали.